# LINQ grouping results and ordering them by specific order

Tags: c#, linq

I want to order my data like this:

1. Group my data by some value called "Type"
2. I want to order groups by specific order of Types, for example:
   I have defined order : TYPE1, TYPE3, TYPE4,TYPE2

   And now I want all set to look like this:

   -first few rows are TYPE1 Type rows,

   -next few rows are TYPE3 Type rows,

   .....

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Is `Type` an enum or string, or something else?

Comment: Type is my enum, and I want to have specific order basing on enum values

Comment: `var typeSequence = new []{ TYPE1, TYPE3, TYPE4, TYPE2 }; var ordered = items.OrderBy(item => typeSequence.IndexOf(item.Type));` If that's a performance issue, you might try `var typeSequence = new Dictionary<YourEnum, int>{{TYPE1, 1}, {TYPE3, 2}, [...]};` and then `typeSequence[item.Type]`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more information on how your data are structured. The best way would be with a [mre] of the code being used. You could also include the research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mentioned that `Type` is an enum.  I can see two easy options for ordering this, 1. change the value of the enumeration members or, 2. use a custom ordering.

**Solution 1 - Changing enumeration member values**

This is quite simple, but may not fit in with your requirements (i.e. the enumeration values may be dictated elsewhere or need hardcoded values).

Change the value of the enumeration members to be fixed values in the order you want:

```
public enumeration YourEnumName {
    TYPE1 = 1,
    TYPE3 = 2,
    TYPE4 = 3,
    TYPE2 = 4
}
```

**Solution 2 - Use a custom list for ordering purposes**

When conduction your ordering, create a list to dictate the order you want:

```
YourEnum[] orderList = new [] { YourEnum.TYPE1, YourEnum.TYPE3, YourEnum.TYPE4, YourEnum.TYPE2 };

var result = yourData.OrderBy(x => orderList.IndexOf(x.Type));
```

The limitation with this second solution is that if you have an item that does not exist in the `orderList`, then you will find that these are placed together in the order they were received at the start of the list.  There are solutions to that issue but I'm not clear on whether you will experience it.